# Using functions in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am very new to ext-js.

I have a container grid and what i need to do is this: if the difference between 2 columns in a row is bigger than 2 the row should be in red.

i cant figure out how to do so.

```
columns: [
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                                dataIndex: 'val_1',
                                                text: 'val_1'
                                            },
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                                dataIndex: 'val_2',
                                                text: 'val_2'
                                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this example

Ext.onReady(function(){

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {

fields: [ 'price', 'change'],

data: [

[ 0, 0],

[ 2, 3],

[ 0, 1],

[ 2, 3],

[ 5, 6],

[ 0,0]

]

});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

title: 'Array Grid',

store: store,

columns: [

{text: 'Price', width: 75, dataIndex: 'price'},

{text: 'Change', width: 75, dataIndex: 'change'}

],

viewConfig: {

```
stripeRows: false,

getRowClass: function(record) { 

    return record.get('price')+record.get('change') > 2 ? 'change-row-color':'';  

    } 

},
```

height: 200,

width: 200,

renderTo: Ext.getBody()

});

});

css:

.change-row-color .x-grid-cell {

background-color: #ffe2e2;

color: #900;

}

Answer (score 1):

Use [`getRowClass`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getRowClass) method:

> Override this function to apply custom CSS classes to rows during
>   rendering. This function should return the CSS class name (or empty
>   string '' for none) that will be added to the row's wrapping div. To
>   apply multiple class names, simply return them space-delimited within
>   the string (e.g. 'my-class another-class'). Example usage:

```
 viewConfig: {
     getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
         return record.get("valid") ? "row-valid" : "row-error";
     } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use TemplateColumn

```
function getDivForHighlightOnDiff2(x,y,text) {
    var highlighter = "";
    if (Math.abs(x-y) > 2) {
        highlighter = 'class="shinyRed"';
    }
    return '<div '+highlighter+'>'+text+x+'</div>';
}

highlightOnDiff2Template1= "{[getDivForHighlightOnDiff2(values.val_1, values.val_2,'val_1')]}"
highlightOnDiff2Template1 = "{[getDivForHighlightOnDiff2(values.val_2, values.val_1,'val_2')]}"

columns: [
{
    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
    tpl: highlightOnDiff2Template1
},
{
    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
    tpl: highlightOnDiff2Template2
}
```